# What is the fastest way to count the number times all of the elements in an array occur in a string?

Tags: arrays, perl, string-matching

I have a string (`$info`) that looks something like this:

```
$info = "Complete1:1,ATTCGGCTAGGGCTAGCTAGCTAG,Complete1:2,ATTTGAGAGGGATCGCGCCAT,..."
```

And an array (`@codes`) that looks something like this:

```
@codes = ("ACTTTCGGGGCATCGGATCG", "ATTGCATGGGCATGGCATGGCATG", "ACGGGATGGGCATGCTAG",...);
```

The array `@codes` contains some elements that match (1 or more) parts of `$info` and some elements that do not match `$info` at all.

What would be the fastest way to count the number times all of the elements in `@codes` matches the string `$info`?  Thanks!

Comment: Does your `$info` fit into memory? What is the size of the array? The fastest method would probably be to construct regexen and match against them. (And your array declaration is probably wrong, what you've stated there is an array with only one element).

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches come to mind for doing this:

```
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @codes;
my $re = qr/,(?:$pat),/;

for my $info (...) {
   my $padded_info = ",$info,";
   my $count; ++$count while $padded_info =~ /$re/g;
   ...
}
```

or

```
my %codes = map { $_ => 1 } @codes;

for my $info (...) {
   my $count = grep $codes{$_}, split /,/, $info;
   ...
}
```

I layed out the code as if multiple strings are checked for the code in `@codes`. Reusing calculated values is from where the real savings will come.

I'll leave the benchmarking and micro-optimization to you, since that will depend on your data and usage pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Performance might not be stellar, depending on the size of your source string, but you can optimize later if you need to.

```
my %results;

for my $code (@codes) {
    my $count = () = $info =~ /$code/g;
    $results{$code} = $count;
}
```